# How to print .docx attachments from Gmail iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, ms-office, gmail, printing

When I open a .docx formatted attachment with the Gmail iPad app, there's no option to print.

I've installed the MS-Office for iPad app, but so far as I can see, there's no way to change default applications to get my attachment to open with MS-Office.

Is there a straightforward way around this?

Comment: Have you signed-in to the Office app?  Also, how are you trying to print the .docx from Gmail?  What iOS version?

Comment: Can you move the attachment to Files? from there you can open with Pages, which has an option to Print. With normal Mail application in iPad, such attachment  can be  also opened/sent to Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to add the printing functionality to Gmail's iOS app (using the share button).

### Workarounds

1. Open the attachment in Mail.app (which allows for printing)
2. Save/copy the attachment to another app that allows for printing i.e. Files.app, Google Docs, MS Word etc.